# How to run a task before build in 2021 gradle Kotlin syntax in an Android project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I read a lot of answers to multiple questions like this, but they are all very old and use arcane/obsolete syntax in groovy and/or are not suitable for Android projects.

I have a task.

```
tasks.register("asd") {
  doFirst {
    exec {
```

How do I run it when build starts in an Android `app/build.gradle.kts` file?

I have printed both `tasks` and `project.tasks` names and I have tried

```
tasks.named("build").dependsOn(":asd")
tasks.named("app:build").dependsOn(":asd")
tasks.named(":app:build").dependsOn(":asd")
project.tasks.named("build").dependsOn(":asd")
project.tasks.named("app:build").dependsOn(":asd")
project.tasks.named(":app:build").dependsOn(":asd")
```

It either fails with `Task <name> not found in project` or it does nothing.

I tried with `doFirst`, `doLast` and neither (directly `exec`) and still nothing.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean)? Which task are you running and how (command line)?

Comment: @jannis does your question mean that I am in theory doing the right thing but there might be another problem in the rest of my `build.gradle.kts` script?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 6):

So I found the right way to go about it

```
android {
  project.tasks.preBuild.dependsOn("asd") 
}


tasks.register("asd") {
  doFirst {
    exec {}
  }
}
```

No need for the `:` when referring to the task.
The `build` and `preBuild` tasks are accessible from `(project.)tasks`.

`doFirst` was necessary otherwise it would loop endlessly.
`tasks.register` allowed the task to run when it needed and not immediately, which happens if we use `create`